# Get every bean from bean.xml file

Tags: java, spring

I have an xml file with beans  which look like this:

```
<bean class="org.example.domain.Person" id="1">
        <property name="first_name" value="Jillian"/>
        <property name="last_name" value="Palethorpe"/>
        <property name="email" value="jpalethorpe0@accuweather.com"/>
        <property name="company_name" value="Layo"/>
</bean>
```

It has up to 30 beans with class person and id from 1 to 30.

Now i want to print them
I know that I could do this like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    Person first = applicationContext.getBean("1", Person.class);
    Person second = applicationContext.getBean("2", Person.class);
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
}

}
```

But is there a better way to get all of the "beans" or persons from this xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `getBeansOfType()` method in the `ApplicationContext` which can return all beans of a given type. The beans will be retuned as a map which the key is the name of the bean while the value is the bean instance.

```java
Map<String, Person> beans = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Person.class);

Person person1 = beans.get("1"); 
Person person2 = beans.get("2");

List<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<>(beans.values());
```